# Lista no Android Studio

Tags: java, android, lista

Tenho um listview que traz dados quando eu adiciono no meu `ArrayAdapter`. Por exemplo: `adaptador.add("algum dado")`.

Mas eu queria que este listview trouxesse dados de um cadastro de produtos, como o nome, quantidade e preço que estão nos EditTexts. O problema é que na minha tela de inserçao não consigo fazer referência ao `ArrayAdapter` pra adicionar estes dados, pois a tela de lista e inserção sao duas telas diferentes.

Se possível também, gostaria que exibisse o total de preço de cada valor dos produtos adicionados. As duas telas de lista e inserção são respectivamente "`CarregarTelaLista()`" e `"Carregar Tela3()`"

Segue o código:

```
public void CarregarTelaLista()
{
    setContentView(R.layout.lista);



    btnadd = (ImageButton) findViewById (R.id.btnadd);
    volte = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.volte);

    lstprodutos = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstprodutos);

    adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    adaptador.add("Produto: " + txtnome.getText().toString() + "Quantidade: " + txtquantidade + " Preco: " + txtpreco.getText().toString());

    lstprodutos.setAdapter(adaptador);

    //VOLTAR
    volte.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CarregarTela1();
        }
    });
    //ADICIONAR PRODUTOS
    btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CarregarTela3();
        }
    });

}

    public void CarregarTela3()
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.tela3);


        spi = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);
        final ArrayAdapter adapter =  ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.unidade,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spi.setAdapter(adapter);

     /*   ListView lstprodutos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstprodutos);

        ArrayAdapter<addprodutos> adpProdutos = new ArrayAdapter<addprodutos>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        lstprodutos.setAdapter(adpProdutos);  */

        btnvoltar3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnvoltar3);
        insere = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insere);

        txtnome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtnome);
        txtpreco = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpreco);
        txtquantidade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtquantidade);

        lstprodutos = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstprodutos);

        adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        insere.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if(txtnome.getText().toString().isEmpty() || txtpreco.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "há campos vazios", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
else {
                    adaptador.add("Produto: " + txtnome.getText().toString() + "Quantidade: " + txtquantidade + " Preco: " + txtpreco.getText().toString());


                    CarregarTelaLista();

                }
                lstprodutos.setAdapter(adaptador);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tem duas telas de inserção 'CarregarTelaLista' e 'CarregarTela3' ?

Você poderia tentar inserir a informação em uma tela e em uma outra tela você carrega o ListView. Clicando no ListView você pode jogar para uma tela de edição e nessa tela você pode fazer a logica da quantidade x valor.
Não consegui compreender muito bem o que você está querendo. Mas deixo aqui a minha sugestão.